# how can i add matplotlib to python3?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, matplotlib

i've wanted to import matplotlib in python3 on my mac. that gave me an error:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: bad magic number in 'matplotlib': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

if done some research here on stackoverflow and i guess 2.7 shoulnd't be in the sys.path, right? how can i remove this one? any other recommendations?

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

edit: someone just mentioned this one:

```
sys.path = [x for x in sys.path if "python2.7" not in x]
```

worked well. the error is gone but a new error appeared...

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

so i tried to reinstall matplotlib with

```
brew install matplotlib --with-python3
```

that dind't work well:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (caskroom/cask, homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
planck

==> Installing matplotlib from homebrew/science
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/f0/9da3ef24ea7eb0ccd1
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/8c/7c9869454bdc53e72f
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/4b/137dea450d6e1e3d47
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/60/6ac26ad05857c60130
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/bb/bf325351dd8ab6eb3c
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/fc/39a3fbde6864942e8b
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/e1/aca6ef73a7bd322a7f
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/b2/238e2590826bfdd113
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/2f/49e53b0d0e94611a2d
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
Last 15 lines from /Users/-/Library/Logs/Homebrew/matplotlib/09.python:
  File "setupext.py", line 874, in include_dirs_hook
    import numpy
  File "numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  File "numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray


READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html

These open issues may also help:
Matplotlib –with-python3 doesn’t compile (because of qhull) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5175
graph-tool dependencies and headers missing during installation https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5583
gubbins: influences on quast https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5752
rampart: Build a bottle for Linuxbrew https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/5414
nest: revision for gsl https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/5888
Formula affected by Homebrew/brew#2482 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5470
nest: Enable concurrent Python 2 & 3 support https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/5620
Migrate most notable formulae to core https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/6331
gubbins - Failed to import the site module (since python 3.4 -> 3.5) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3490
graph-tool: symbol binding failed https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3259
```

Comment: can you check `PYTHONPATH` env. variable?

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH returns a blank row
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: How did you install matplotlib?

Comment: i guess with brew... not sure. tried to install it once again... new error new edit

Comment: You might have reasons to use brew or original python distribution, but if there are no specific reasons, then I always recommend to use Anaconda/Miniconda to install python on Windows or Mac. - https://www.anaconda.com/

Comment: that was a great idea! works fine so far. i just can't install opencv with conda --> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv3 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.